# Wie kann man am besten „(you) guys“ übersetzen?

Tags: slang

Sind

> *Leute, Kerle, Jungs (vorausgesetzt, dass es nur da Männer gibt)*

gute Übersetzungen des englischen „(you) guys“?

Wären etwa die folgenden Beispiele richtig?

> 1. Hey Leute, beilt euch!
> 2. Kerle, kommt ihr mit? Wir fahren schon.
> 3. Jungs ich bin dran. <sup>(Etwa bei einem Kartenspiel)</sup>.

In diesem Sinne wird auch *du* anscheinend wie folgt verwendet wird:

> Ehm, **du** (winzige Pause), ich wollte mal fragen, was hast du für heute Abend vor?

Wäre deren Plural, etwa

> Ehm, **ihr**, ....was wollt ihr machen?

auch in Ordnung?

Comment: Es heißt übrigens "Jungs, ich bin dran / ich bin an der Reihe". "Drankommen" ist aber dennoch nicht ganz falsch. In einem Spiel, wo du übersprungen werden kannst (z.b. Mau Mau, Uno) kannst du sagen: "Jungs, komm ich auch noch mal dran?"

Comment: Ich war falsch. Stimmt: *bin dran* ist das, was ich meinte.

Comment: Modalpartikel sind nicht vorfeldfähig. In den genannten Beispielen steht Leute etc. aber im Vorfeld. Man kann auch keinen Satz mit du, ihr etc. pp. konstruieren, der typischerweise ein Modalpartikel verlangt: Wäre ich *doch nur* am Meer! \*Wäre ich Leute/du/ihr am Meer!

Comment: Ja, ich kann den Tag löschen. Trotzdem: "[Es] existiert noch eine Klasse von Modalpartikeln (manchmal ‚Partikeln mit abtönender Bedeutung‘ oder ‚abtönungsfähige Partikeln‘ genannt), die oft ebenfalls zu den Modalpartikeln gezählt werden, jedoch vorfeldfähig sind. Dazu gehören z. B. *fein, ganz, gerade, gleich, einfach, erst, immerhin, schließlich, überhaupt und ruhig.*" Auf der Wikipedia-Liste der Bediengungen einer Modalpartikel ist die, die einzige, die nicht erfüllt wird.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Leute* ist nicht nur gut, sondern glaube ich auch die gängigste allgemeingültige Variante. Spontan fällt mir gar nichts anderes ein. Somit ist Beispiel (1) richtig.

*Kerle* wird so nicht verwendet. *Kerl* ist synonym zu *Typ*. In Satz (2) verwende ich daher auch *Leute*. Ein paar Beispiele für *Kerl*:

> Da hat mich zuletzt so ein Kerl[=Typ] angequatscht.
>   Siehst du den Kerl[=Typen] da hinten.
>   Das ist vielleicht ein komischer Kerl[=Typ].

*Jungs* ist durchaus gängig bei Männern. Bei Frauen ist es dann *Mädels*.

> Jungs/Mädels, wie siehts aus? Ziehen wir los?

*Ihr* verwendet man so nicht. In deinem letzten Beispiel würde ich wieder zu *Leute* greifen, oder mal ein andere Platzhalter anstatt einer "Anrede":

> Ehm, sagt mal, was wollt ihr machen?

Answer (score 4):

Teils ist die englische Formulierung "you guys" dadurch motiviert, dass das einfache "you" nicht mehr eindeutig als Plural erkennbar ist. In diesem Fall kann man das "guys" bei der Übersetzung weglassen, da dieses Problem im Deutschen nicht besteht.

Comment: In Texas gibt es für you im Plural "y'all" --- you all.

Comment: Ja, das ist eine andere Variante.